# Making an image scale down when window resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a background image set as a background, and I want it so, when the user scales down the window, it will resize with it:

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallax {
  background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg");
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}
```

I got it to work when I changed  `background-size: cover; to contain`, but it cuts out some of the image from the left and right side.

Fiddle Link : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37268/)

Comment: your fiddle works perfectly here - the image resizes (?)

Comment: @Johannes not when u shrink the window it dosent

Comment: really, it does - I am on Firefox Mac

Comment: If i had contain then yes it works perfect

Comment: @Johannes if you change it to contain thats the effect i wont, without the left and right side been cut

Comment: but then top and bottom are cut off

Comment: Ye i dont want that, does it make sense? sorry English is not the best, i just want an image to resize as the window gets smaller, so if they view it on an iphone it should look like the full image but smaller

Comment: you could define `background-size: 100% 100%`, but this will distort the image (its proportions). If you use a photograph as a background image this usually isn't desired

Comment: Ye i dont want that :(

Comment: what * do*  you want? You can't scale width and height of an image independently and not get distortions...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h You see this link? Change the width in this to 704 and change the window size , thats what i want

Comment: But that's not a background image, but a regular `img` tag, where the height changes proportionally to the width and simply pushes the lower border down if it needs more space (or moves it up if it needs less space). Just use an `img` tag (and no background-image) if you want this.. I added a snippet like this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below makes the background image responsive too when a `window` is `resized`. I have updated your `css` code, removed `min-height` and background `fixed` and made the `padding` percentage in top and bottom.

```css
 .parallax {
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/coffee_hand_glass_scarf_113704_1366x768.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
  padding: 30% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my comments, here is what I wrote about in the last comment - a regular `img` tag with `width: 100%`and `height: auto` instead of a background-image:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/coffee_hand_glass_scarf_113704_1366x768.jpg">
</div>
```